# How to build PHP 7 with default packages, default location, and zts enabled on centos 6

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

First off, let me just say that I have been searching around for days now and I have small bits of information from every source so what I need now is to just glue everything together. This is my first time developing with PHP on Centos 6.8 and it has been fine with the basics until I needed multithreading for a function.

I found that I need to compile PHP 7.0.7 from source with:
`--enable-maintainer-zts` and maybe even `--enable-pthreads` although, I don't think that's necessary anymore for PHP 7. Problem is, I don't know what else is necessary to have a functioning PHP. Every post I found have a different purpose for their PHP so it's different everytime. Also, after `make install` (after using --prefix=/usr/local/php) it does install to that directory but that isn't the same directory where yum would install it so I have to export PATH, but if that could be avoided, please let me know.

So I guess, just to summarize, what do I put between: `./configure <here> --enable-maintainer-zts` so that it has default packages and what should `--prefix=` be so that it installs where yum would install it?

[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php) has this list, but again, do I want/need everything?

Some other sources I found:

[Source 1](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/) - Kinda helps but I'm not on Debian
One has: `--enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --with-curl --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --with-zlib-dir --with-regex --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-soap --enable-sockets --with-xmlrpc --enable-zip --with-zlib --enable-inline-optimization --enable-mbregex --enable-opcache --enable-fpm --prefix=/usr/local/php`

Another has: `--prefix=/usr/local/php \
  --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --with-curl \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-xmlrpc \
  --enable-soap \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-gd \
  --with-jpeg-dir \
  --with-png-dir \
  --with-mysql \
  --with-pgsql \
  --enable-embedded-mysqli \
  --with-freetype-dir \
  --with-ldap \
  --enable-intl \
  --with-xsl`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any need for a) a self-compiled PHP and b) for Thread safety? ZTS is usually not needed unless you have a very special need. There is probably already a compiled PHP with pThreads in a repo with the generic extensions.

Comment: The need for the self-compiled PHP is to enable Thread safety (apparently, it can only be enabled during compile time). I would love it if I don't need to compile PHP myself but I haven't found any (or more like, I don't know what to look for). I need ZTS for pthreads is what I'm thinking because I need multithreading in PHP. If there are better ways, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, just looked up. pThreads requires ZTS and ZTS can only be enabled during compilation. According to PHP.net you only need a PHP build with ZTS and then you can install pThreads using PECL. Maybe you can find a repository with a ZTS-enabled PHP build. With a quick google search I couldn't find a CentOS repository with PHP7 ZTS.

Comment: @JedV Did you ever figure this out? If so can you point me in the right direction? I really don't want to have to compile a new php setup if I don't have too. Thanks in advance either way.

Comment: @NinjaKC Sorry but I never got the multi-threading to work on PHP 7. There were too many incompatibilities at the time so I just decided on multithreading everything else.